# Why would you subsitute spaces for - in a url for an AJAX Delete request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, url

```
  var item = $(this).text();
  item=item.replace(/ /g,'-');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'DELETE',
    url: '/todo/' + item,
    success: function(data){
      //do something with the data via front-end framework
      location.reload();
    }
  });
```

I saw this code, and I was wondering why you would want to subsitute all of the spaces in the delete url with dashes?

Answer (score 1):

Spaces are not allowed in a URL. You can encode them, of course, but it might just be simpler and more readable to turn them to dashes. Take a look at the url for this question, for example.

Comment: And spaces usually get encoded to `%20` by browser which makes url hard to read